# How can I filter my nested object depends one one property?

Tags: jquery, arrays, angularjs, filter

I have one object array. I m trying to filter which have not car ? My object is like below:

```
var obj = {
    personName: 'John', 
    Car: {
        Brand: 'A',         
        Age: 2 
    }
},{
    personName: 'Alice', 
    Car: {
        Brand: 'A', 
        Age: 2 
    }
},{
    personName: 'Martin', 
    Car:{}
}]
```

How can I do it? I don't want to use `$each`, `for` loop or anything like that.

Comment: `I don't want to use $each, for loop or anything like that` A very obscure restriction, given that it is impossible without them. Even using something like `$.filter` would use a loop internally.

Comment: maybe with linq.js  can be used. But I m not sure which way is the best?

Comment: Again, linq.js will use a loop. It is literally impossible to do this on a dynamic length object without one.

Answer (score 1):

use recursive function like

```
var people = [{
     personName: 'John',
     Car: {
         Brand: 'A',
         Age: 2
     }
 }, {
     personName: 'Alice',
     Car: {
         Brand: 'A',
         Age: 2
     }
 }, {
     personName: 'Martin',
     Car: {}
 }]
 var count1 = people.length;
 $scope.NoCar = function (arr, count2) {

     if (count2 == 0)
         return;
     else {
         if (arr[count2 - 1].Car == {} || arr[count2 - 1].Car == null) {
             console.log("No Car");
         }
         count2--;
         $scope.NoCar(arr, count2);
     }
 }
 $scope.NoCar(people, count1);
```

I'm not sure if the code works , but I'm sure the logic is correct

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm you can use native javascript filter function to the array:

```
$scope.noCar = obj.filter(function(v){
  return !v.hasOwnProperty('Car') || !v.Car.hasOwnProperty('Brand');
});
```

And use the returned array. (But this is the exactly method used by $filter('filter')) https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js#L155

Then is the same the above code to this:

```
$scope.noCar = $filter('filter')(obj, function(v){
  return !v.hasOwnProperty('Car') || !v.car.hasOwnProperty('Brand');
})
```

The native method is the most efficient way always, this is run directly over the engine (V8, etc)